# SAXParser.parse method in java not working in eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse

I have followed online tutorials and created 2 classes (subclass and main class) to read the XML file using SAX parser by extending `DefaultHandler` class. Everything is good but when I'm try to write the method `SAXParser.parse(String URI, DefaultHandler object)` in Eclipse it is showing below error image.
Please help me what I have done wrong here.

[image: Error image]

```
public class mainclass{
public static void main(String []args)
{
        DefaultHandler dff=new subclass();
        SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try
        {
        SAXParser sp=spf.newSAXParser();
        sp.parse("Trial.xml", dff);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("exception is "+e);
    }
}
}

public class subclass extends DefaultHandler{
boolean bheader=false;
boolean bdetail=false;
boolean blpn=false;

public void startDocument() throws SAXException
{
    System.out.println("Starting the start document method");
}
public void endDocument() throws SAXException
{
    System.out.println("End document method called");
}
public void startElement(String uri,String localName,String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
{
    System.out.println("Start element method called "+qName);
}
public void endElement(String uri,String localName,String qName) throws SAXException
{
    System.out.println("end element method called "+qName);
}
public void characters(char ch[],int start,int length)
{
    System.out.println("Characters method called "+new String(ch,start,length));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are importing DefaultHandler class from wrong package. you should import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler

Comment: By changing the package as you suggested my problem solved.